# Typescript - How can I dynamically define a type from an array of possible values?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I would like to find a way to dynamically define a type from an array of possibilities.

I have a map as shown below where the keys are the types's name, and the corresponding values are arrays of what that type can be.

```
export const typeOptions = {
  areaOfStudy: ["politics", "mathematics", "biology"],
  ageRange: ["1821", "2225", "26plus"],
  societyCategory: [
    "Debate Society",
    "Basketball Society",
    "Football Society",
    "3D Modelling Society",
  ],
}
```

I would like to find a way to infer from the object above the following:

```
export type AreaOfStudy = "politics" | "mathematics" | "biology";
export type AgeRange = "1821" | "2225" | "26plus";
export type SocietyCategory =
  | "Debate Society"
  | "Basketball Society"
  | "Football Society"
  | "3D Modelling Society"
```

Any ideas or tips on how I could do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `typeof` combined with `as const`

`typeof` gives you the type of a value. `as const` says that it should use the exact values.

```js
export const typeOptions = {
  areaOfStudy: ["politics", "mathematics", "biology"] as const,
  ageRange: ["1821", "2225", "26plus"] as const,
  societyCategory: [
    "Debate Society",
    "Basketball Society",
    "Football Society",
    "3D Modelling Society",
  ] as const,
}

export type AreaOfStudy = typeof typeOptions.areaOfStudy[number]
export type AgeRange = typeof typeOptions.ageRange[number]
export type SocietyCategory = typeof typeOptions.societyCategory[number]
```

Comment: But this won't work if the array is created dynamically (e.g. by the user) as Typescript has no way of checking that. The values of the array must be known at compile time for this

Comment: I am getting: type string is not assignable to type 'readonly [....]' if I try to initialize a variable

Comment: My bad. I fixed it by adding `[number]` after the type definition (which could be a specific index or number for all).

Comment: That's great, thank you so much!! What do "as const" and "[number]" do?

Comment: I've used [const assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) to use the exact values (`politics, math, ...`) instead of `string[]` and `[number]` to select the elements instead of the whole array. For latter I didn't find documentation, but I think it's basically the same as `arr[0]` which would return the type of the first element, but joining all elements instead. Maybe open a new question if that answer is not enough for you :)